# Warning during App build on Android studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.6

I just updated Android studio 3.6.1 and while building my app I got following warning:

> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
>   android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources
>   The raw resource for unit test functionality is removed.

What is this warning about and how to remove this?

Comment: Update your version of roboelectric?

Comment: @Blundell I am using the latest version only:                               testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1'

Comment: Downgrade your version? :-) It's an issue in Robolectric I believe

Comment: Post your build.gradle.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [robolectric instructions say](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/) that this configuration is not necessary with Android Studio 3.3+

So, please check your `gradle.properties` file and remove this line:

```
android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=true
```

Comment: Also check both `project/gradle.properties` and `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just cleared my gradle cache files and that seemed to have resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by removing configuration at `gradle.properties`. see below:

```
#android.enableBuildCache=true
```